# Find the probability of B

Tags: probability

Suppose you roll a fair 6-sided dice three times. There are $6^3$ possible outcomes and each is equally likely.

Let $A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4, A_5,$ and $A_6$ be the events that the last value is 1,2,3,4,5, and 6 respectively.

Let B be
the event that the first value is less or equal to the second value and the second value is less or equal to the
third value.

What’s the probability of $A_4 ∩ B?$

I have done the work and got that

$$ A_1 = \frac{1}{216} = .004\\
A_2 = \frac{3}{216} = .013\\
A_3= \frac{4}{216} =.018\\
A_4 = \frac{7}{216} = .032\\
A_5 = \frac{11}{216} = .051\\
A_6 = \frac{16}{216} = .074\\
$$

Now, the probability of $P(A_4 ∩ B)$ is

$$P(A_4) P(B)$$

But how do I find P(B)?

Comment: Not following.  $A_i$ is the probability that the last of three rolls comes up $i$, no?  But if so, $A_i=\frac 16$ for all $i$.

Comment: $A_1=A_2=A_3=A_4=A_5=A_6=\frac16$ These are independent of the first two rolls.

Comment: Also:  events $A_4$ and $B$ are far from independent.  Knowing that the last roll is a $4$ severely restricts the ways in which $B$ might happen (first roll must be $≤ 4$ for example).  Therefore you can't just multiply the probabilities.

Comment: I thought $A_1$ would be the set in which it ends with i.  So the set B would be the sum of all the rolls above - meaning 1+3+4+7+11+16?

Comment: Still not following.  I'll write up a solution based on the what I believe the definitions mean.  If I am misreading, perhaps you'll be able to point out where.

Comment: I think OP's $A_i$ are what the problem denotes by $A_i \cap B$.  (The values are almost right, but not quite.)  The true values are $P(A_i \cap B) = \frac{n(n+1)}{432}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the OP points out, each ordered triple of rolls has the same probability, namely $\frac 1{6^3}$.

Assume the last roll is a $4$ (so event $A_4$ has happened).  Let's proceed to enumerate the rolls that comprise $A_4\cap B$, working by cases according to the first roll. Clearly, if we specify the first and third rolls, the only thing left to specify is the second.

Case I.  first roll is a $1$.  Then the second roll could be $\{1,2,3,4\}$ so we have $4$ instances.

Case II.  first roll is a $2$.  Then the second roll could be $\{2,3,4\}$ so we have $3$ instances.

Case III.  first roll is a $3$.  Then the second roll could be $\{3,4\}$ so we have $2$ instances.

Case IV.  first roll is a $4$.  Then the second roll must be $\{4\}$ so we have $1$ instance.

All in all we see that there are $10$ "winning" rolls, so the probability of getting one them is $$\frac {10}{6^3}\sim .0463$$